# Removed remote. But remote branch still shows

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I've added a remote, so I could checkout a coworker's code.

```
$ git remote add coworker git@ourgitserver.local:...
$ git fetch coworker
$ git checkout coworker/theirbranch
$ git checkout -b mycopy
```

The code looked good. So I do some cleanup:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git remote remove coworker
$ git branch -D mycopy
```

But their remote branch still shows up:

```
$ git branch -a
remotes/coworker/theirbranch
```

I've done `git fetch -p --all`, `git gc --prune=now` and those did nothing.

I can't do `git branch -D coworker/theirbranch` because the remote doesn't exist. Neither can I `git fetch -p coworker` because that remote does not exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you remove the remote before cleaning up the branches?

Comment: I didn't think that would matter. Wouldn't you think that by removing a remote, the references to the remote branches would go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git remote remove coworker` *should* have deleted the corresponding remote-tracking branches, and does in the quick tests I ran, so I am not sure what went wrong here.

To manually clean up, though, you may run `git branch -d -r` (note both flags) on each remaining remote-tracking branch:

```
git branch -d -r coworker/theirbranch
```

Comment: Thank you. The `-r` flag did the trick. I'll mark as accepted when the time minimum is reached.